# iptables allow only traffic with specific data

Tags: iptables

I don't know if this is at all possible, but I want to rate limit all UDP traffic coming from random source ports with a specific hex string like this:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p udp --dport 27015:27030 -m string --algo kmp --hex-string '|ffffffff54|' -m limit --limit 15/s --limit-burst 10 -j LOG
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p udp --dport 27015:27030 -m string --algo kmp --hex-string '|ffffffff54|' -j DROP
```

But, I want to accept all traffic that stays under this limit, so if I do this next:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m string --algo kmp --hex-string '|ffffffff54|' -j ACCEPT
```

All traffic is still being blocked according to the first rules.

However, if I do:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 27015:27030 -j ACCEPT
```

Everything works including the rate limiter but then traffic without that string coming from other ports is permitted as well which I don't want.

So how do I accomplish this? Or am I doing something that's not possible, allowing traffic on pattern only instead of port?

Comment: Can you just confirm what you want to do is allow ONLY traffic that contains that particular string and ONLY at a certain limited rate?

Comment: Hi Matthew yes that's correct indeed! But the issue I guess that I would first need to open the port before the string matching is even possible.